# Gridsome - How to add category slug to post URL

Tags: vue.js, gridsome

I want to add the category slug into my blog post's URL. ie: my-website.com/caterory-slug/post-slug

I'm setting the path like this:

```
module.exports = {
  siteName: 'Gridsome',
  siteDescription: 'A WordPress starter for Gridsome',

  templates: {
    WordPressCategory: '/category/:slug', // adds a route for the "category" post type (Optional)
    WordPressPost: [
      {
        path: (node) => {
          return `/${node.categories[0].slug}/${node.slug}`
        }
      }
    ]
    // WordPressPostTag: '/tag/:slug' // adds a route for the "post_tag" post type (Optional)
  },
  plugins: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

But I get undefined in the URL for the category slug. I could replace the category's slug with ID and it would work. The category's ID would be in the URL. I can access the category's slug in the template, but not in the URL.

In this same template my graph ql query looks like this:

```
<page-query>
query Home ($page: Int) {
  allWordPressPost (page: $page, perPage: 10) @paginate {
    pageInfo {
      totalPages
      currentPage
    }
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        path
        excerpt
        categories {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</page-query>
```

And the repsonse for the query is:

```
"edges": [
  {
    "node": {
      "id": "581",
      "title": "Chatbot Lazy Loader Plugin",
      "path": "/categories-0-slug/chatbot-lazy-loader-plugin/",
      "categories": [
        {
          "slug": "wordpress"
        }
      ]
    }
  }...
]
```

Comment: There is no direct prop `slug` on `node`?

Comment: @pai.not.pi , can you elaborate more? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: For you to be able to access `node.slug`, `slug` needs to be a direct child of the `node` object, which based on the code in your post doesn't seem like it is. Could you paste what the `node` object response looks like?

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm trying to access the category's slug when constructing the post's URL.

So why does slug need to be a direct property of node? Wouldn't that give me the blog post's slug?

The response for my query can be found above in my edited post.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong in the code apart from `node.slug` being `undefined`. Can you log the `node` object in the `path` function?

Comment: This is what's returned for node.categories:

`categories: [ { typeName: 'WordPressCategory', id: '3' } ]`

I don't know how to get the slug to load as part of that object.

Comment: Could you just log the whole `node` object? I imagine it's returning an object 1 level higher than you need.

Comment: Sure, here's a gist of the whole node object: https://gist.github.com/joseph-farruggio/13c9bc1616224f7682ca32329503152f

Comment: Your query has the object you need but the node in the function doesn't? how are you calling the path function?

Comment: I just updated the post. The first code snippet shows the path function from the gridsome.config.js file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218173/discussion-between-joseph-farruggio-and-pai-not-pi).